# FutureBuilder's snapshot is always either null or has no data

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to flutter and I hope this problem can be easily solved, but up until now I have no idea what's going wrong.

I have an app where I would like to return a list of users after the search button is pressed. I think that a FutureBuilder with a ListView.builder is the correct choice for this, but somehow I can't get my data to appear in the FutureBuilder even though my async function is definitely finding results.
My future:

```
Future<List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>> results;
```

the button:

```
onPressed: () {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
        _formKey.currentState.save();

        setState(() {
            results = null;
            searched = true;
        });
    results = getGuestData(widget.place['placeName'], query);
    }
},
```

Async function:

```
Future<List<Map>> getGuestData(String placeName, Map query) async {
  List<Map> result = [];
  CollectionReference guestsRef = Firestore.instance
      .collection(XXX)
      .document(XXX)
      .collection(XXX);

  if (query['date'] == null) {
    guestsRef
        .where('lastName', isEqualTo: query['lastName'])
        .where('firstName', isEqualTo: query['firstName'])
        .getDocuments()
        .then((doc) {
      if (doc != null) {
        result = doc.documents.map((x) => x.data).toList(); \\debugger shows this is working
      }
    }).catchError((e) => print("error fetching data: $e"));
  }
  return result;
```

and finally the problem:

```
FutureBuilder<List<Map>>(
      future: results,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          List guests = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: guests.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                ... //do stuff here
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    )
```

snapshot.data will indeed turn out to be a List, but the size is always 0 despite the getGuestData query finding users.

Comment: snapshot error has always been null as far as I have seen in the debugger

Comment: ok, why are you using `Future.then` and not `await` in `async` method?

Comment: That worked somehow! Like I said, I am very new to Flutter and I thought that await and then were equivalent statements. Thank you very much

Comment: sure, your welcome